# Is there any way to replace "words" in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typesetting

I made a book in Illustrator, and I would like to replace a word with another word (e.g "Bread" into "Rice"). If I was using MS Word, I could simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and do a word replace. How about in Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to "Main menu > Edit > Find and replace".

It's exactly the same as other applications, just without the keyboard shortcut (it's a less commonly used feature, and those keys are used for other things: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Paste in Front, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for Show/Hide Edges).

---

Incidentally, making a book in Illustrator is quite unusual. It's more common to assemble the book in InDesign and use Illustrator for illustrations, which are then placed into the InDesign file.

Comment: ah thank you for the answer... I usually using Illustrator first and then exported to indesign for finalizing. Yeah its quite unusual workflow, because I more familiar with Illustrator tool